# Rails 6 not reporting hidden_values from form for multiple object construction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to create a form that populates fields for each of the users pulled from a query, then submits all objects at once. With how my code is currently set up when the entire form submits only the non-hidden fields are sent to the controller.

```
<%= form_tag evaluations_path(method: :post) do |f| %>
   <% Ingroup.where(group_id: Group.where(course_id: Project
                  .find(params[:project_id]).course_id)).each do |mem| %>
      <h3>Evaluation for <%= "#{mem.user.Fname} #{mem.user.Lname}" %></h3>
      <%= fields_for :evaluation do |form| %>
         <% form.hidden_field :project_id, :value => params[:project_id] %>
         <% form.hidden_field :user_id, :value => mem.user_id %>
         <div class="field">
            <%= form.label :score %>
            <%= form.number_field :score %>
         </div>
         <div class="field">
            <%= form.label :comment %>
            <%= form.text_area :comment %>
         </div>
      <% end %>
   <% end %>
   <div class="actions">
      <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

EDIT: I added some additional code from the terminal and controller view.
EDIT 2: Removed the plural from evaluations and am still not seeing the hidden field values being passed.

Terminal Error:

```
Started POST "/evaluations?method=post" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-12-02 21:55:08 -0500
Processing by EvaluationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"9pSgJJh3iE1doRy81Jhh3gHEgEJZt7pzcZw3C5EZeMEBh22VG8pmMKtHTwFml+Sj/XZmb3pBv6CmOLb9WvEVkQ==", "evaluation"=>{"score"=>"1", "name"=>"asdf"}, "commit"=>"Submit", "method"=>"post"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/evaluations_controller.rb:31:in `create'
  Evaluation Exists? (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "evaluations" WHERE "evaluations"."user_id" IS NULL AND "evaluations"."project_id" IS NULL LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/evaluations_controller.rb:31:in `create'
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/evaluations_controller.rb:31:in `create'
No template found for EvaluationsController#create, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 9ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms | Allocations: 5851)
```

Controller:

```
class EvaluationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_evaluation, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    @evaluation = Evaluation.new
  end

  def create
    @evaluation = Evaluation.new(evaluation_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @evaluation.save
        format.html { redirect_to @evaluation, notice: 'Evaluation was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @evaluation }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @evaluation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_evaluation
      @evaluation = Evaluation.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def evaluation_params
      params.require(:evaluation).permit(:project_id, :user_id, :score, :name)
    end
end
```

Comment: Show your controller code, specifically your strong parameters.  If you could also show a log from your server to show what is being sent for the call that would be helpful.

Comment: Have you inspected the page to see what's the generated html? specifically those hidden fields

Comment: Yes, they're not populating in the source code.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out the issue. Had <% instead of <%= around the hidden fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your strong param says:

```
  params.require(:evaluation).permit(:project_id, :user_id, :score, :name)
```

but in your view you have:

```
<%= fields_for :evaluations do |form| %>
```

Remove the final `s` for `evaluations` and it should work.

---

Related with your hidden fields, you're missing to use `<%=`. Try with:

```
<%= form.hidden_field :project_id, :value => params[:project_id] %>
<%= form.hidden_field :user_id, :value => mem.user_id %>
```

Comment: Thank you, that did fix the parameter issue, but it's still not posting the hidden fields.